# What are the differences in importing css using these three techniques?

Tags: css, angular

Is There any difference to import to an Angular project a CSS lib (eg bootstrap) considering the options below:

**Angular.json (npm)**

```json
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

**Angular.json (CSS file locally)**

```json
"styles": [
  "assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

**styles.scss (CSS file locally)**

```
@import "assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: Styles imported in the `angular.json` file are globally. you can use it everywhere in the project. Styles included `locally in the component` are available only for that component (and its childs, if it have them).

Comment: @emarzo, **not** put the .css in assets folder if you included in angular.json styles (you can include in any folder of your app). All the styles you included in angular.json are "merge" in an unique file. so, the file copied in assest folder never is used

Comment: Angular.json applies the style to your whole app. As you can see, even styles.scss is being imported by angular.json. If you remove it from angular.json, your application will not use the style, unless you reference it inside your component styles: styleUrls: ['./xxxx.css'].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the first solution, because:

- All three will end up in main CSS bundle
- But 2. and 3. will also have original bootstrap inside assets. Even though it's used in bundle, it won't be removed from assets - which are a part of a build as it is.

Also, if you update Bootstrap it's way easier doing so by NPM.

Comment: Does this mean if I use method 2 or 3 I will have bootstrap duplicated in the dist folder and the user will download bootstrap twice (once in the bundle and other in the asset)?

Comment: No, it won't download it because it won't be referenced, but it will be in dist.